# Primefaces commandbutton to add image not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[image]

I'm add user defined image commandbutton button its not working.I try to below code:

```
 <p:commandButton id="addMoreButton" value=""
  action="#{ContactDetails.addMoreButtonAction}" image="#{General.image}"/>
```

In replace of image to use icon attribute icon="addMoreImageButton" but it also not working. 
css:

```
.addMoreImageButton
            {
                 background-image: url("#{GeneralPageAttributes.addMoreImageButton}");            
            }
```

I need only image in button not text then what attribute to choosen it.

Comment: What is not working ? what are you seeing and what do you want to see ?

Comment: specify image not show in commandbutton. It  only show ^ symbol

Comment: open it in chrome and right click inspect. See if the image URL is correct

Comment: Is there a perfect image link in #{General.image}?

Comment: @Parkash Kumar link is come from bean (/faces/resources/images/AddIcon.png)

Comment: The issue is with your link. Try with a hard-coded link

Comment: @ Shahzeb I check insepect element icon and image attribute path is not shown but i use graphics image to check path is find

Comment: In below i add screenshot graphic image has work but same not work in commandabutton image attribute

Answer (score 2):

There are following ways, you can create a image button: **(Tested Code)**

**[Using commandButton]**

```
<p:commandButton id="addMoreButton" value="" action="#" 
    image="http://c.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/christmas_surprise_four_in_one/png/128x128/frost_button.png" />
```

If the `'image'` attribute for commandButton is specified, button will be of type image without any text on it, even if the `'value'` attribute is specified with some String.

**[Using commandLink]**

```
<p:commandLink id="addMoreButton1" value="" action="#">
    <p:graphicImage url="http://c.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/christmas_surprise_four_in_one/png/128x128/frost_button.png" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Use your bean action in place of #.
Also specify styleClass or style attribute to further beautify your controls.